# Spring MVC - json string is truncated to 500 characters

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I would like to send image encoded in base64 format in json. The problem is that the string has more than 3k chars, it is automatically truncated to 500 chars.  and the trailing ellipsis appeared in this string.

```
...     
"image64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCEUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAGccAigAYkZCTUQwMTAwMGFhNzAzMDAwMDZhMDQwMDAwNWIwNTAwMDBhMzA1MDAwMGZhMDUwMDAwMWYwNzAwMDAyYTA4MDAwMDZmMDgwMDAwYjIwODAwMDAwNDA5MDAwMGM3MGEwMDAwAP/iAhxJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAAgxsY21zAhAAAG1udHJSR0IgWFlaIAfcAAEAGQADACkAOWFjc3BBUFBMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD21gABAAAAANMtbGNtcwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACmRlc2MAAAD8AAAAXmNwcnQAAAFcAAAAC3d0cHQAAAFoAAAAFGJrcHQAAAF8AAAAFHJYWVoAAAGQAAAAFGdYWVoAAAGkA...",
...
```

My method is annotated with @ResponseBody. When I am trying to debug at the last line of my method I get the full string in response (more than 3k chars).

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public MyResponse getResponse(HttpServletRequest request) throws CMSItemNotFoundException
{
    ...
    return response;
}
```

I've made a quick test using jQuery...

```
$.get("http://.../get", function(data) {
    console.log(data.image64.length);
});
```

... and I've got 500 in my console

Can anybody help on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

There was just a problem with the return type. The response seems to be complete when the return type is array of bytes.